# Read a file 2 by 2 lines using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I try to read a simple TXT file using Linq, but, my dificult is. read a file in 2 by 2 lines, for this, I made a simple function, but, I belive I can read the TXT separating 2 by 2 lines...

My code to read the text lines is:

```
    private struct Test
    {
        public string Line1, Line2;
    };

    static List<Test> teste_func(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> exemplo = new List<Test>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]).Where(x => x.StartsWith("1") || x.StartsWith("7")).ToArray();

        for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
        {
            Test aux = new Test();
            aux.Line1 = lines[i];
            i+=1;
            aux.Line2 = lines[i];

            exemplo.Add(aux);
        }

        return exemplo;
    }
```

Before I create this function, I tried to do this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]). .Where(x=>x.StartsWith("1") || x.StartsWith("7")).Select(x =>
                new Test
                {
                    Line1 = x.Substring(0, 10),
                    Line2 = x.Substring(0, 10)
                });
```

But, it's obvious, that system will be get line by line and create a new struct for the line...
So, how I can make to get 2 by 2 lines with linq ?

> --- Edit
>   Maybe is possible to create a new 'linq' function, to make that ???

```
Func<T> Get2Lines<T>(this Func<T> obj....) { ... }
```

Comment: I ran the program and understand it obtains lines starting with 1 or 7.  The result is returned as a single struct with 2 properties.  I do not understand "2 by 2 lines with linq"?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Do you simply want to concatenate the two lines into one?  If so just add another property that does just that to the Struct.  And while you are at it make the struct immuteable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<B> MapPairs<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> sequence, 
                                                 Func<A, A, B> mapper)
    {
        var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var first = enumerator.Current;
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var second = enumerator.Current;
                yield return mapper(first, second);
            }
            else
            {
                //What should we do with left over?
            }
        }
    }
```

Then

```
File.ReadAllLines(...)
    .Where(...)
    .MapPairs((a1,a2) => new Test() { Line1 = a1, Line2 = a2 })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's a linq extension method, you just need to supply a method that takes two `A`s (which are strings if they are lines of a file) and returns a `B` (an object of type `Test`)

Comment: @Rob It's not a LINQ method.  It's just a custom extension method you wrote that emulates a particular style of programming found in the LINQ methods.  LINQ is simply the classes in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: Note that you should really be using `ReadLines` not `ReadAllLines`, and ideally not call `ToList` unless it's truly needed to allow the lines to be streamed, rather than eagerly loaded into memory.

Comment: @Servy: Yes - fair points. I would normally use `ReadLines` and omit `ToList`, but was emulating the usage in the question, where the original example returns a list.

Comment: THanks :) ... btw, if I have more lines, for example 7 lines ?

Comment: Boris's approach would probably be easier. You don't want to write 7 calls to MoveNext() :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
File.ReadLines("example.txt")
    .Where(x => x.StartsWith("1") || x.StartsWith("7"))
    .Select((l, i) => new {Index = i, Line = l})
    .GroupBy(o => o.Index / 2, o => o.Line)
    .Select(g => new Test(g));

public struct Test
{
    public Test(IEnumerable<string> src) 
    { 
        var tmp = src.ToArray();
        Line1 = tmp.Length > 0 ? tmp[0] : null;
        Line2 = tmp.Length > 1 ? tmp[1] : null;
    }

    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very interesting, but, the 'new Test(g)', not work, the struct don't receive a arguments for constructor... how I can use your method ?

Comment: @Alexandre A struct can have a constructor with params. It cannot have a parameterless constructor. I changed the code to struct. If you don't like a constructor you can always inline code into the last `Select`, but to me this is more clean.

Comment: THanks :) ... btw, if I have more lines, for example 7 lines ?

Comment: @Alexandre Just change the line `o.Index / 2` to `o.Index / 7`, and modify Test struct and its constructor.